# Search beyond first level of sub folders on Windows and/or Mac?

Tags: search, windows-search

Is there a way to expand the search past the first level of sub folder? If I have sub folders a few levels deep, how can I expand my search to documents in these folders? If I have the following setup:

```
root
 + subfolder1
 + subfolder2
 + subfolder3
 + etc...
```

How would I access wordDoc1.docx whose path would be `root/subfolder3/sub3a/sub3a_1/wordDoc1.docx` (3 levels deep)?

Comment: Define "search".

Comment: Search - typing a keyword for a document and/or its contents in the search bar in windows explorer or mac finder

Answer (score 0):

If your folder options have been set up correctly, `Windows search` should be searching beyond the first level. Below is what my folder options look like:

[image: Folder options]

With the above settings, all possible levels are queried using a search term. If your settings are the same, you shouldn't have any issues searching past the first level.

Comment: I tried that and it only returns results in the folder I search in and its sub folder(s). Any content in a sub-sub folder(s) isn't returned.

Comment: Hmmm. Have you tried the Restore Defaults option?